# AutoMapper Conditional Entity Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, automapper-3

I have a db entity which stores the Order Addresses like this...

[image]

And I have the BLL classes like this...

```
public class DeliveryAddress
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string PersonyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public List<string> AddressLines { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

and another class like this...

```
public class InvoiceAddress
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string PersonyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public List<string> AddressLines { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to map the EF entity to the above classes on the basis of AddressType column. Can anybody explain me how to do that ?

**UPDATE**

I want to map to `OR.DeliveryAddress` if the addressType is "Delivery" and to `OR.InvoiceAddress` if the addressType is "Invoice"

So far, I have been able to do this, but I don't know how to apply condition on the entity mapping level...

```
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderAddress, OR.DeliveryAddress>()
       .ForMember(d => d.City, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.city))
       .ForMember(d => d.CompanyName, o => o.UseValue(string.Empty))
       .ForMember(d => d.CountryCode, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.countryCode))
       .ForMember(d => d.Id, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.id))
       .ForMember(d => d.PersonyName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.name))
       .ForMember(d => d.Zip, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.zip));
```

**UPDATE 2**

After discussion with @Yuliam [Here is the Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X93DEM) that I could come up with for my problem...

Comment: Do you want to map to `OR.DeliveryAddress` if the addressType is "Delivery" and to `OR.InvoiceAddress` if the addressType is "Invoice" ?

Comment: yes, you are right...

Comment: I don't think you should use subtypes here but just copy the address type. AutoMapper doesn't have tooling for this.

Comment: @GertArnold What do you mean by not using subtypes ?

Comment: Ah, they're not sub types. Well, just use one type including an address type property.

Comment: I can't. This is the code that I have inherited from some other developers and I can't change the code structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a customer mapper to object. And also you don't have to specify each property using `ForMember` because if the difference is only upper case / lower case (unless for `PersonName`), by default `AutoMapper` is case insensitive when mapping the property name.

Create a custom mapper to object.

```
public class AddressConverter : ITypeConverter<OrderAddress, object>
{
    public object Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var o = context.SourceValue as OrderAddress;
        if (o == null) return null;

        if (o.addressType == "Delivery") return Mapper.Map<OR.DeliveryAddress>(o);
        if (o.addressType == "Invoice") return Mapper.Map<OR.InvoiceAddress>(o);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then define the mapper.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderAddress, OR.DeliveryAddress>()
    .ForMember(d => d.PersonyName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.name));
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderAddress, OR.InvoiceAddress>()
    .ForMember(d => d.PersonyName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.name));
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderAddress, object>().ConvertUsing<AddressConverter>();
```

Usage.

```
var orderAddressDto = Mapper.Map<object>(orderAddress);
```

The actual `orderAddressDto` type will be based on the `addressType`. If you have an interface or base class for `OR.DeliveryAddress` and `OR.InvoiceAddress` that would be more strongly type. Then replace the object type with the interface / base class.

Comment: I have `List<OrderAddress>` in the `Order` entity and when I call `AutoMapper.Map<Order>(order);`. Will it work?

Comment: @NaveedButt, you can just map the property like this `var result = AutoMapper.Map<object[]>(order.OrderAddresses);`

Comment: I used this, but it did not work, so not marking your answer. I am still looking for the answer. I managed to do it using `Linq` queries, i.e., populate the object manually...

Comment: @NaveedButt, Did you map the order address directly? or from the order? How did you map it?

Comment: @NaveedButt, in the question there is no usage of map, just configuration, let me clarify again, did you use `var orderAddressDto = Mapper.Map<object>(orderAddress)` or `var orderDto = Mapper.Map<object>(order)` or `var addressesDto = Mapper.Map<object[]>(order.OrderAddresses)` or something else ?

Comment: I used this... `var orderAddressDto = Mapper.Map<object>(orderAddress)`

Comment: @NaveedButt, it's working fine [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PKR7Lf), probably something missing at your side that is not properly configured or wrong usage

Comment: I am sorry, if I am unable to explain my problem, but this is my problem: https://dotnetfiddle.net/X93DEM Hope you can help me now...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60951/discussion-between-yuliam-chandra-and-naveed-butt).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try taking a look at `ResolveUsing`

Semi-pseudo code, as I don't know what your entire Domain Model looks like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderObject, OrderDto>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Address, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(oo => oo.Type == Invoice ? oo.InvoiceAddress : oo.DeliveryAddress));
```

I'm assuming here that you have an actual Order entity, which you're trying to make to an 'OrderDto' which only contains one address field.

Comment: There is a `List<OrderAddress>` in the Order entity plus. This is the way to convert the Entity to DTO. What would be the way to convert the DTO back to Entity? I think I would have to use Yuliam's method for that, right ?